# После запуска VB машины все висит

Tags: linux, virtualbox

Версия 35~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 25 10:13:43 UTC 2018, после запуска VirtualBox какой либо машины, черный экран и все виснет, перед этим просил это modprobe vboxdrv. Подскажите, пожалуйста.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удаление полное - sudo apt remove virtualbox*
И установка новой версии решило проблему.